# Finding out the "tips" of currently installed MacPorts packages or graphing the dependency tree

Tags: mac, macports, dependencies

My Mac accumulated a lot of installed ports that I may not need when reinstalling it soon.

I want to only install those packages which I know I'm using, but to filter them out of the huge list of `port list installed` is impractical.

I'm looking for a way to out put a list of just those installed packages which don't have any other package depending on them. Better yet, I'd love to have a way to visualize the dependencies.

Any ideas on how to accomplish either one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I was wrong last time. I think now the correct command you could use is `port list requested`. You can also set and unset requested status with `port setrequested` and `port unsetrequested`, respectively.

Comment: Note this only works correctly if you are using 1.9 or newer with the sqlite registry format. If you had an older installation, you need to change your `portdbformat` in macports.conf first and manually mark software you want as requested. With the new registry format dependencies will always be considered unrequested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the script `port_cutleaves` to find installed ports which you no longer need. It interactively walks through the leaves of the dependency tree and allows to trigger the actions keep or uninstall. It also provides a man page describing more advanced options.

Example:

```
$ sudo port install port_cutleaves
$ sudo port_cutleaves
[Leaf 1 of 13] samba3 @3.2.15_1 (active):
  [keep] / (u)ninstall / (f)lush / (a)bort:
```

Comment: Too bad they used an unexpected (or, now-outdated?) connotation of "leaves": "installed ports that are unrequested and have no dependents.". In contrast, Homebrew defines "leaves" as "formulae that are not dependencies of another installed formula."
Perhaps it would be better if `port_cutleaves` were now called `port_cutorphans`.